# performance issues in sprite kit with efficient code

Tags: sprite-kit, xcode7

I read all the posts I found about improving performance but my problem is a bit different.

I have a simple physics-based game. no super fancy stuff.

I´ve got max. 40 nodes on the screen and a few sklabelnodes.

my code is efficient - every node which moves outside the screen gets removed from his parent and Iv'e got just 4 physicBodys at once. textures are not to big - max 250x250 which are preloaded in an atlas.

the problem is that it works for a minute or so and then it starts to stutter for 4-5 sec and then it works fine again. that stuttering doesn't appear on a certain point. sometimes it does on startup and sometimes after a few minutes.

I don´t know what to do.

I load my ad´s on another thread and otherwise there isn't anything to load.

EDIT:

NO shapeNodes. 
XCode 7 + iPhone 6plus (9.3.2)

@Alessandro Ornano

my update method only handles the background images. i already tried without bg´s. same problem. i read about performance issues in iOS9 
do you know something about that?

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime{

//BG
if (self.background1.position.x >= self.size.width*1.5) {
    self.background1.position = CGPointMake(self.background2.position.x - self.background1.size.width+1, self.size.height/2);
}

if (self.background2.position.x >= self.size.width*1.5) {
    self.background2.position = CGPointMake(self.background1.position.x - self.background2.size.width+1, self.size.height/2);
}

//BG CLOUDS
if (self.backgroundClouds1.position.x >= self.size.width*1.5) {
    self.backgroundClouds1.position = CGPointMake(self.backgroundClouds2.position.x - self.backgroundClouds1.size.width+1, self.size.height/2);
}

if (self.backgroundClouds2.position.x >= self.size.width*1.5) {
    self.backgroundClouds2.position = CGPointMake(self.backgroundClouds1.position.x - self.backgroundClouds2.size.width+1, self.size.height/2);
}
```

}

Comment: Two question for you: have you test it in simulator? Do you use SKShapeNodes ? Please report these answers in your question so your question will be more clear, report also some code thank you.

Comment: I don't use shapeNodes and the simulator never worked for me because I don't get higher frameRates as 20-25. Even with a blank scene.

Comment: Put yourself in my shoes: how can I help NeoGER89 without see any code?    Because usually this kind of thing happened after 100 nodes and during a SKShapeNodes massive use so, can you simply show your update method?

Comment: please look at my question.

Comment: @NeoGER89: A simple rule to find out which part of your code is causing bad performance. Just start commenting parts of your code until the performance issue goes away.

Comment: @NeoGER89 I think you must refactor your way to implement a parallax background, I see you move big nodes in your method and this way is not very good  man

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano: I totally agree with you

Comment: Thank you I tried that before. @appzYourLife. It appears randomly. And as is said, I tried without background and in addition to that i commented the update methods. This is just an endless floating background. And I use the same 2 pictures for the nodes.

Comment: @NeoGER89: Try running your game on your iPhone while looking at the `Xcode Debug Navigator` (_CMD + 6_). If you see the CPU, Memory, Disk or Network usage to increase too much when the issue happen you'll have a good hint about the nature of the problem.

Comment: I did that. I have a Max cpu of 50% and 90mb in memory. Ad's are loading in dispatch and just on startup. I really couldn't figure out what this problem causes it's just randomly stuttering.

Comment: You will have to post code,  just because you claim it is efficient, does not mean it is. You claim that every node that is outside of the scene gets removed from the parent.  Now this is not always efficient.  SpriteKit will not render anything outside of the screen bounds,  so unless you have sprites doing physics body type calculations, or particles, your best bet is to just pause the node so that animation stops. I am sure you have other inefficient things going on as well.

Comment: Also, you have ads?  then this may be causing your problem because of an ad loading.  Just because you throw it on a separate thread, do not assume it is.  What ad service are you using?  all UI work is done on the main thread, so it is possible that you did not setup the ad service correctly, and are getting locked up when ads are being drawn in the UIView of the banner.

Comment: I'm using only interstitials from adMob. Which load their ads on startup. And present it at the end of the game. Before my game starts I already have a log in the -didReceiveAd delegate method. There is nothing loading while the game runs on the main level. I create my sprites with a physicsBody and a moveTo Action. It starts on the right side, move to the left and after the action has completed it gets removed from his parent. What code should I post if I don't know what it causes? I post you all you need if you want to help me. Just tell exactly what. Thank you

Comment: Are you constantly creating new sprites and physics bodies?  That will definitely cause to happen if you need to make multiple bodies in 1 frame

Comment: Constantly yes but only one Every Second. It's just a rectangle physicsBody. I have max 4 of these sprites At once on the screen and my playerSprite. I guess I'll wait until the next update gets releases. Maybe it's really this version